# Nestjs new component throws error, issue with dependencies injection

Tags: javascript, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

My nestjs when being run is throwing 502 Bad Gateway.
This code works fine when this module is commented through app.module.ts
Code is simply talking to database by connecting data repository

Issue of conflict is

```
imports : [
 TypeOrmModule.forFeature([KYCStatus, User, Country], 'customerDB'),
]
```

in service constructor

```
@InjectDataSource('customerDB')
private readonly dataSource: DataSource,
```

and at the time of using the dataSource
const countryRepository = this.dataSource.getRepository(Country);

but i am getting the error

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the customerDB_KYCStatusRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument customerDBDataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is TypeOrmModule a valid NestJS module?
- If customerDBDataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If customerDBDataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing customerDBDataSource */ ]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using multiple `DataSource`s. Make sure you set the `name` field on the configuration.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  // NOTE: This must be set on your non-default database.
  name: 'customerDB',
  useFactory: ...,
  inject: ...,
}),
```

See https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases and https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/86.